# StructureMap 3 Breaking Change

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap, structuremap3

In previous versions of StructureMap, I have a code like this:

```
_container.Configure(config => 
    config
        .For<ILogger>.Use<TLogger>.Ctor<string>("loggerName")
        .Is((IContext ctx) => ctx.Root.RequestedType.ToString))
```

Using this, I was able to pass the class name to my logger and it was very helpful in auto wiring scenarios.

After updating to StrucureMap 3, the above code shows error and I cannot find the right code for StructureMap 3.

**TL;DR;** Where is Context.Root? How can I access it in **StructureMap 3**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was wrong in the first place.

Instead of `Context.Root`, I can use `Context.ParentType` and accomplish what I wanted.

A sample, available in this link: http://docs.structuremap.net/UsingSessionContext.htm#section1 (Logger Sample)helped me find the solution.